# Sending large JSON via jQuery ajax errors with 404, TypeMismatchError, or "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, iis

I'm working on an ASP.NET web application for uploading files and I'm having an issue when the upload size gets large.

I'm sending a JSON string to a C# WebMethod. The JSON contains files (base64) and metadata about the file (input by the user).

Here's the structure of my JSON:

```
{
    "files" : 
    [
        {
            "filename" : "test.txt",
            "fileBase64" : "base64string",
            "customMetadata" : "bla bla bla"
        },
        {
            "filename" : "test2.txt",
            "fileBase64" : "base64string",
            "customMetadata" : "bla bla bla"
        }
    ]
}
```

UploadInput class:

```
public class UploadInput
{
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public string fileBase64 { get; set; }
    public string customMetadata { get; set; }
}
```

Web method signature:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string UploadFiles(List<UploadInput> files) { ... }
```

When the JSON is below ~30MB, everything works fine.

When the JSON gets around 30MB, I get a 404 not found error. (IE, Chrome, and Filefox)

When the JSON gets around 50MB, I get a TypeMismatchError. (Just IE)

When the JSON gets around 60MB, I get a "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error. (Just IE)

I captured the web traffic and the request isn't being sent when I encounter the TypeMismatchError or the "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation" error, so they must be occurring on the client.

Here's my JavaScript:

```
function uploadFiles() {
    $.blockUI({ message: null });

    var formData = {
        "files" : _files
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'Images.aspx/UploadFiles',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            // remove the upload rows
            $(".upload-row").remove();

            // clear the _files array
            _files = [];
            updateCurrentUploadSize();

            // display the result
            displayUploadResults(result.d);
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // display the error
            $("#upload-results-div")
                .html("Request: " + XMLHttpRequest.toString()
                    + "\n\nStatus: " + textStatus 
                    + "\n\nError: " + errorThrown);
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.unblockUI();
        }
    })
}
```

The arguments to the error function aren't giving me any detailed information, just 404, TypeMismatchError, and "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation". Is there a way for me to obtain more information on the errors?

I already set `maxJsonLength="100000000"` and `maxRequestLength="100000000"` in my Web.config file. Are there any other settings that would prevent the request from being sent?

Any ideas and suggestions would be helpful, I'm completely stuck on this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The default [`maxAllowedContentLength`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms689462(v=vs.90).aspx) is 30000000, which is why I got the 404 error when the upload size was more than 30MB. I added the following to my Web.config file and I no longer get the 404 error.

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```