# Internet explorer throws TypeMismatchError at POST upload request with large body

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, file-upload, large-file-upload

I have few files (~30Mb every) that needs convert to base64 and upload for server. After uploading part of files IE11 throws TypeMismatchError. File content is a base64 string that it is not encoding problem. Panel of network requests do not contents it, request fails before sending. Another browsers are working without errors. How to fix it?

```
function post(url, data, timeout) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        xhr.onreadystatechange = (result) => {
            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
                resolve(xhr.responseText);
            }
        };

        xhr.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(event);
        };

        xhr.timeout = timeout;

        xhr.send(data);
    });
}
function handleFileSelect() {
    post('/upload', LARGE_FILE_DATA_BASE64).catch(error => {
        // Throws TypeMismatchError error after few uploads.
    });
}
```

Google says about this similar problem only here: https://helperbyte.com/questions/276626/jquery-deferrer-typemismatcherror-when-you-bulk-load-data-cant-find-what-this-might-mean

Comment: I suggest you if possible then trying to refresh the page after each upload using the js code. It can be possible that the large files are causing some memory-related issues. You can try to test it and let us know whether it is working in that way or not.

Comment: Reloading of page is not suitable in my case

Comment: Can you please inform us, which exact IE 11 version and OS build you are using for making this test? Approximately How many files you are trying to upload? Did you check on which line error occurs? Does error occurs on the same line every time?

Comment: IE 11.1217.17763.0, Windows 10, 4 files 30Mb without errors, on 5th file throws error.
reject(event); - this line every time

Comment: Are you using the IIS server to host your application? I have seen some similar issues. If you are using the IIS server then try to modify your web.config file and update 
 maxAllowedContentLength="100000000" See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39171285/sending-large-json-via-jquery-ajax-errors-with-404-typemismatcherror-or-not-e Let us know, whether it is helpful in your issue or not.